# Is there a screen which keeps the *current* action logs for the latest push on GitHub Actions?

Tags: github

Each set of action logs in my experience in GitHub Actions goes under https://github.com/termsurf/chocolatey-task/actions/runs/7620716992/job/20755895856. Then you have to:

- click "Actions" tab
- click the latest build
- click on the build logs

That's kind of annoying when debugging, is there a screen or way to just keep it on the latest logs?